# I am not able to trigger Paypal REST API webhook events

Tags: paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I'm trying to implement the Paypal REST API for a client and I'm at the point where I need to test the webhook system. I can not get the API to generate an event; a successful payment should generate one, I've also tried using the REST API to issue refunds, and I've tried issuing refunds from the developer sandbox. None of those activities have generated an event for me.

For example, if I execute the command:

`curl -v -X GET -H 'Authorization: Bearer VALID_BEARER_TOKEN' 'https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/notifications/webhooks-events'`

I get this:

`{"events":[],"count":0}`

Even after a dozen or so successful payments and maybe a half-dozen refunds, in both sandbox and live, I see `"count": 0`. The sandbox merchant center and transaction detail both are aware of the correct state of each transaction, and if I query the `/v1/payments/payment/{id}` resource, I see the correct state for that `{id}`.

Operationally, I have everything set up correctly:

- the webhook uri is registered correctly in the app details, with subscriptions to all event types
  [image: webhook details]
- the endpoint has a valid SSL Certificate
  [image: server ssl details]
- the endpoint has no firewall or other security that would prevent a successful SSL connection (I've tested this thoroughly)

I have application logging ratcheted up to the finest detail, with no results. I have tcpdump listening on the webhook target machine just to see if any handshake is attempted, also with no results. I've even tried the old "delete and recreate" trick with the app, which didn't help. I've also registered a new PayPal merchant account and encountered the same problem.

I do see IPN traffic for one of the accounts that had a default IPN handler enabled. I would prefer to use the webhooks if at all possible, the reason my client wants to do this in the first place is to get away from IPN.

Am I missing a setting somewhere? Is there some magic undocumented flag? Or is webhook support too new and I shouldn't rely on it and just stop wasting my time and go back to IPN?

Comment: I have the same problem, did you manage to solve it somehow?

Comment: Looks like it's not supported yet...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing wrong on your side. If you do sale, paypal webhooks only support echeck case for now. PayPal is adding webhooks support covering other funding sources for sale payment, estimated release is in next Jan.

Comment: Thank you. I'll use IPN for now then.

Answer (score 1):

To update this thread, PayPal has added webhooks support for other funding sources for sale payment.

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/rest-webhooks-overview/

Comment: They are still not firing in the sandbox for me. If I use the WebHook simulator, it works fine. But transactions in the sandbox don't fire off and calls to my url.

Comment: @CarolAndorMartenLiebster did you manage to work with WebHooks in Sandbox? The only cases that are working for me is when a plan is created, and when a subscription agreement is created. The Payment.Sale.Completed is not firing when daily billing is affected, but the payments do appear in the notification section, so I know they are happening. Any idea?